# How to read properties file in Play framework 2.5

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.5

I'm using Play framework to make website.
But had problem when I tried to read properties file.
I searched and try with `[Play.application().resourceAsStream("test.properties")]` but have error `[Play.application().resourceAsStream("test.properties")]`.

but had error:

> [the method aplication(Aplication) in the type Play is not applicable
>   for the arguments()]

what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You need to inject `Configuration` object:

**Scala**

```
class HomeController @Inject()(conf: Configuration) extends Controller{

  def post() = Action{
    val testProp = conf.getString("test.properties") 
...
```

**Java**

```
public class HomeController extends Controller{

  @Inject
  private Configuration configuration;

  public Result post(){
    final String testProp = configuration.getString("test.properties") 
...
```

Comment: if possible please add either full specified Type or import block.